# Rewriting an Javascript Arrow-function

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, arrow-functions

Can anyone explain and help me how to re-code this Javascript Arrow-function?

```
var Data = JSArray.filter(v => v.tags.some(k => k.name === "test"));
```

I'd just like to translate it to Javascript default functions instead of an Arrow-function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change an [arrow function `() => expression`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), from

```
a => a
```

to

```
function (a) {
    return a;
}
```

Together, you get

```
var Data = JSArray.filter(function (v) {
        return v.tags.some(function (k) {
            return k.name === "test";
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this using the [Babel.js Tryout](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=latest%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20Data%20%3D%20JSArray.filter(v%20%3D%3E%20v.tags.some(k%20%3D%3E%20k.name%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22test%22))%3B%0A&playground=true)

```
"use strict";

var Data = JSArray.filter(function (v) {
  return v.tags.some(function (k) {
    return k.name === "test";
  });
});
```

For an explanation see [MDN: Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Babel.js Tryout has helped me out, too!

Answer (score 0):

You have a quite pretty one-liner here, without arrow functions it gets more verbose. Try something like this:

```
var Data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < JSArray.length; i++) {
    var e = JSArray[i];
    if (e.tags.some(function(k) {return k.name === "test"})) {
        Data.push(e);
    }
}
```