# React HOC without arrow function syntax

Tags: reactjs

I have a HOC React function written in es6 syntax like so:

```
const withHOC = Component => (props) => {
  return (
    <Component
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

How can I write this in es5 syntax?

eg: `function HOC(){}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rewriting an Javascript Arrow-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698880/rewriting-an-javascript-arrow-function)

Comment: It's basically a function that returns another function that returns a Component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

given HoC or HoF definitions, will be a function that returns another component/function

if i understand correctly, maybe what you want is:

```
function withHoC(Component) {
  return function(props) {
    return <Component {...props} />
  }
}
```